# Cannot align two buttons side by side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've added display: inline block; and have tried list-style: none;. However nothing works. I would apreciate any possible answer.

Html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: white; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 
100%; height: 70px; ">

<a href = "index.html">
<h3 id = "title" style="color: #0099ff;">
Student Sources
</h3>
    </a>

<a href = "stuff.html">
<button id = "stuff" style="margin-right: 900px; display:inline-block;">
Articles/Presentations
</button>
    </a>

    <a href = "aboutus.html">
<button id = "aboutus" style="display:inline-block; float: right;a">
About Us
</button>
    </a>

<!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

---

```
.navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light{

background-color: blue;
color: blue;
}

#topics{

}
a, a:hover, a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
}


#title{
transition-duration: .1s;
}
#title:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration-color: #FFAE00;

}

#stuff{

padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
background-color: white;
color: #0097CF;
border-style: none;
margin-right: 800px;
margin-bottom: 0px; 
color: #0091AE;
transition-duration: .1s;
}

#stuff:hover{


border-style: solid;
border-color:  #FFAE00;
}

#aboutus{
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
background-color: white;
color: #0097CF;
border-style: none;
margin-right: 800px;
margin-bottom: 0px; 
color: #0091AE;
transition-duration: .1s;
}

#aboutus:hover{

border-style: solid;
border-color:  #FFAE00;
}
```

---

It will be very upsetting if someone auto matically says that this question has been answered before. I've tried looking for answers however it does not work.

Comment: [Read the Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#supported-content) .. The navbar needs to contain the supported content. Right now you have links directly in the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing your links. I hope you connected the bootstrap needful task. Here I modified your code.

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a href = "index.html"><h3 id = "title" style="color: #0099ff;">Student Sources</h3</a>
<a href = "stuff.html">
<button id = "stuff" style=" display:inline-block;">Articles/Presentations</button>
</a>
<a href = "aboutus.html"><button id = "aboutus" style="display:inline-block;">About Us</button>
</a>

<!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>
```

**Here I removed only the `margin-right: 900px;` and `float: right` portion.**

**CSS:**

```
.navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light{

background-color: blue;
color: blue;
}

#topics{

}
a, a:hover, a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
}


#title{
transition-duration: .1s;
}
#title:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration-color: #FFAE00;

}

#stuff{

padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
background-color: white;
color: #0097CF;
border-style: none;
margin-bottom: 0px; 
color: #0091AE;
transition-duration: .1s;
}

#stuff:hover{


border-style: solid;
border-color:  #FFAE00;
}
```

**Here I removed only the `margin-right: 800px;` from `#stuff` .**

This is a working fiddle for your question. Check it hope it will help you.
https://jsfiddle.net/tp43gkvn/2/

Comment: but as you can see the two buttons are not right next to each other. One is below the other. The "about us" is below the "articles-presentations'

Comment: Remove the `margin-right` from CSS and remove inline CSS `float:right`.Everything will be okay. And I am improving the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have `display: inline-block` property on buttons and not on `a` elements.
Then you have `margin-right: 800px;` on your buttons, too much to have them side by side.

You have a lot of duplicate properties on your code too. Move all inline style to CSS file.

Comment: Actually I found out the problem. I'm pretty sure bootstap is somehow aligning the buttons with something like `justify-content:space-around;` And I don't know how to change that. Because using display:  `inline-block; list-style: none;` does actually work but I couldn't see it because of the large margins. However, the buttons are evenly spaced out even though I didn't put anything in the code to do that.

Comment: @theSpeciamOne `justify-content:space-around;` is a property of flexbox layout. I suggest you to clean your code first, removing all inline styles and classes, and then add elements class starting from outside tags and looking their behavior with Chrome DevTools.

Answer (score 0):

```
you know what,wrap does two buttons in one <div></div> element and give the div a class name e.g buttonsWrapper.

html template for that:

<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: white; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 
100%; height: 70px; ">

<a href = "index.html">
<h3 id = "title" style="color: #0099ff;">
Student Sources
</h3>
    </a>
<div class=buttonsWrapper>
<button id = "stuff">
<a href = "stuff.html">Articles/Presentations  </a>
</button>

<button id = "aboutus">
<a href = "aboutus.html">About Us</a>
</button>
</div><!--.buttonsWrapper-->

<!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>

in your css,call the buttonsWrapper class and display flex e.g:

.buttonsWrapper{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-around:/*This will space them equally in respect to the parent element width.Then you can use margin to adjust them to your best suit*/
}

Hope this helps!
Next time don't wrap a button inside an anchor tag <a href="#"></a> because,its a bad semantic practice.Rather,wrap an anchor tag in a button element tag.
```

Comment: Also,i suggest you should read up flex and grid because its much more better and current than float when it comes to position items.